# finding bigrams in unicode text with nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to find most common bigrams in a unicode text. Here is the code which I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *
import codecs
line = ""
open_file = codecs.open('s.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
for val in open_file:
    line += val.lower()
tokens = line.split()

bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
finder.apply_freq_filter(1)
a = finder.ngram_fd.viewitems()
for i,j in a:
    print i,j
```

`s.txt` file includes this text: `çalışmak naber çösd bfkd`

Here is the output:

```
(u'\xe7\xf6sd', u'bfkd') 1
(u'naber', u'\xe7\xf6sd') 1
(u'\xe7al\u0131\u015fmak', u'naber') 1
```

But I want it in this format:

```
çalışmak naber 1
naber çösd 1
çösd bfkd 1
```

How can I solve this unicode problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print the elements of the tuple explicitly, not the entire tuple.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *
import codecs
line = ""
open_file = codecs.open('s.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
for val in open_file:
    line += val.lower()
tokens = line.split()

bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
finder.apply_freq_filter(1)
a = finder.ngram_fd.viewitems()
for i, j in a:
  print("{0} {1} {2}".format(i[0], i[1], j))
```

> test.py

```
l = [((u'\xe7\xf6sd', u'bfkd'), 1), ((u'naber', u'\xe7\xf6sd'), 1), ((u'\xe7al\u0131\u015fmak', u'naber'), 1)]
for i, j in l:
  print("{0} {1} {2}".format(i[0], i[1], j))
```

Running:

```
14:58 $ python test.py
çösd bfkd 1
naber çösd 1
çalışmak naber 1
```

Comment: After generating the n-grams frequency from a corpus (text file), how do I get the frequency of an input n-gram from the frequency generated above? ( The input n-gram may or may not be present in the corpus, in case it is present, it should return the frequency, else zero.) Thanks.